# Write a SQL delete based on a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can make the following query and delete in one query ?

```
select krps.kpi_results_fk from report.kpi_results_per_scene krps inner join report.kpi_results kr on kr.session_uid = '0000c2af-1fc8-4729-bb2a-d4516a63107a' 
and kr.pk = krps.kpi_results_fk

delete from report.kpi_results_per_scene where kpi_results_fk = 'answer from above query'
```

Comment: @sebastianbrosch int

Comment: Put the select query inside your delete query, just like this `DELETE FROM ..... WHERE kpi_results_fk = (SELECT krps.kpi_results_fk FROM .....)`. Your select query must return only (1) result. Just incase it returns more than (1), put ANY like this `DELETE FROM ..... WHERE kpi_results_fk = ANY(SELECT krps.kpi_results_fk FROM .....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your case, *NO* need to use `inner join`.

Following query could reduce the overhead of `inner join`

```
DELETE FROM report.kpi_results_per_scene 
WHERE kpi_results_fk IN 
        (SELECT kr.pk FROM report.kpi_results kr 
            WHERE kr.session_uid = '0000c2af-1fc8-4729-bb2a-d4516a63107a')
```

Answer (score 1):

use IN operator:

```
delete from report.kpi_results_per_scene where kpi_results_fk in (
select krps.kpi_results_fk from report.kpi_results_per_scene krps inner join report.kpi_results kr on kr.session_uid = '0000c2af-1fc8-4729-bb2a-d4516a63107a' 
and kr.pk = krps.kpi_results_fk)
```

Comment: Since when in is a clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code bellow:

```
delete from report.kpi_results_per_scene
where kpi_results_fk IN (select krps.kpi_results_fk
                        from report.kpi_results_per_scene krps inner join report.kpi_results kr
                        on kr.session_uid = '0000c2af-1fc8-4729-bb2a-d4516a63107a' 
                        and kr.pk = krps.kpi_results_fk)
```